# "Looking for your teams" highlighted when "How to vote" popup appeared

Tags: bug, design, election, stack-overflow-for-teams

On the [final phase of moderator election](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=election) there's "Read more" link. When you tap this link the "How to vote" popup will appear. In this case link to "Looking for your Teams" isn't grayed out:

> [image]

Not the only "Teams" link is affected, but "Election" tab button as well. And the effect is more interesting, it seems something wrong with Z-order. See the animation below:

> [image]

It's NOT reproducible on narrow mode, hence I think the fix could be simple. Something like take the style sheets from narrow mode and apply to the full width mode.

Comment: hehe, good eyes. Well, that's the latest addition to the sidebar, they most likely forgot to add some CSS class.